# removing duplicate message in ng2-toastr module

Tags: angular, angular-toastr

I am using ng2-toastr module, how to set preventduplicate property to true i.e I dont want to display same message multiple times.

Can you explain how to make this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the help menu about how to ask good questions. Please add some code that demonstrates what you tried, where you failed or what error message you got.

Comment: After having a look at the code, it seems that it's not supported...